# Extending navigator object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to add my own objects and functions to navigator object of JavaScript.
I want to write something like `navigator.AAA.BMethod();`, where `AAA` is my own object and `BMethod` is the method to call.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for adding properties to `navigator`? What have you tried so far?

Comment: yes, I want my code to be like the code of phonegap, that has the following code: navigator.accelerometer.getCurrentAcceleration(accelerometerSuccess, accelerometerError);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a good reason for doing this, anyway you can do it that way:

```
navigator.AAA = {
    BMethod: function () {
        alert('Hello');
    }
};
```

Comment: why? I see that phonegap does it... see here:http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/cordova_accelerometer_accelerometer.md.html#Accelerometer

Comment: In my opinion changing the interface of well known objects is not a good idea. I hope that I helped with my answer :-).